# python3 ZipFile.extractall extracts a empty file

Tags: multithreading, python-3.6, zip

Say I compress a `.txt` file as a `.zip` format with a password 123, the `.txt` file has a few characters like `abcd`. Then I make a new thread, using the `zipfile` lib in python3 to uncompress the `.zip` file. The core code in the thread is:

```
import zipfile as zf
zipf = zf.ZipFile(target)
zipf.extractall(path='./', pwd=password)
```

However, the `.txt` file extracted is empty, namely there is no character in it. Then I do the same experiment with a `.jpeg` image, this time, the image could be extracted perfectly.

I am so confuse about this, could anyone propose a reasonable explanation ?

Comment: As a control, did you try unzipping that zipped text file using the conventional tools (e.g. the Windows desktop, or a Linux option)?  If you did that, what did you see?  Maybe the file is corrupted.

Comment: BTW, this phenomenon sometimes happens , sometimes not, which makes me more confuse..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have tried this, all things goes well. I think the file is normal